# open a 300x300px window login at clicking "myuser"

Tags: web, mobile-website

How do I open a window at the corner of my website where my user icon is located? I am using javascript but take to a interface that replace the whole website. And what I want a only tiny window.

Comment: <div id="avatar" onclick="myFunction()" style="float: right;color:blue">Mi User</div>

Comment: <script>
   var clic = 1;
function myFunction(){ 
   if(clic==1){
  
    document.getElementById("avatar").style.height = "300px";
    location.href="http://www.dominio.com/loginAvatar.php";
   clic = clic + 1;
   } else{
       document.getElementById("avatar").style.height = "0px";      
    clic = 1;
   }   
}

</script>

Comment: You can edit your question and add codes to question itself not comments.